# Return Boolean depending on whether or not string is in alphabetical order

Tags: python

This is what I have so far in python:

```
    def Alphaword():
        alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        x = alphabet.split()
        i = 0
        word = input("Enter a word: ").split()
```

I'm planning on using a for loop for this problem but not sure how to start it.

Comment: Try this and the rest of the Tutorial, it should help you get started. https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Comment: Ignore the coding side of it... how would you go about it as a human if it was written down and you had to work it out yourself? What would your logic be?

Comment: Have a look at the sorted() function in Python. Google it, It could help you with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about it this way - a word containing letters (if they're in alphabetical order) should be equal to itself when forced to be in alphabetical order, so:

```
def alpha_word():
    word = list(input('Enter a word: '))
    return word == sorted(word)
```

That's the naive approach anyway... if you had massive iterables of sequences, there are other techniques, but for strings typed via `input`, it's practical enough.

Comment: +1 I think it is safe enough to presume the OP does not have massive amounts of data

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways:

1. You just loop over each char in the string, use a test like `if a[i]<a[i+1]`.  This works because `'a' < 'b'` is true.
2. You can split string to char list, sort it and compare it to the original list.

Answer (score 0):

Python supports direct comparison of characters. For instance, 'a' < 'b' < 'c' and so on. Use a for loop to go through each letter in the word and compare it to the previous letter:

```
def is_alphabetical(word):
    lowest = word[0]
    for letter in word:
        if letter >= lowest:
            lowest = letter
        else:
            return False
    return True
```